# what is the function of each of these lines?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, tail, head

```
head -$4 $5 > temp
head -$2 $3 | tail -n +$1 >> temp
tail -n +$(expr $4 +1) $5>> temp
```

This is a problem using head and tail. I need a description of each line please thank!

Comment: Did you try to read `man head` and `man tail` before asking?

Comment: RTFM.  "Read the fine manual".  eg. `man head`, `man tail`

Comment: I dont get the $4 and $5 because they refer to arguments and it is not specified( in man)

Comment: $4 ans $5 are command-line arguments.  The fourth ($4) had better be an integer, and the fifth ($5) had better be the name of a file.  Same with $2 (integer) and $3 (file).

Comment: How can you be a shell programmer if you don't understand these lines? They should be explained at the very beginning of any scripting tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

$2, $3, $4 and $5 are all command line arguments called [positional parameters](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams).

Line 1:

Reads the first n lines [represented by $4, a positional parameter] in a file [represented by $5, another positional parameter] and creates a file called "temp" with the output.

Line 2:

Reads the first n lines [represented by $2, a positional parameter] in a file [represented by $3, another positional parameter], then reads the last n lines of that command and appends the output to the "temp" file.

Line 3:

Reads the last n number of lines, where n is equal to ($4 + 1) in a file [represented by $5, yet another positional parameter] and appends the output to the "temp" file.

Comment: `tail -n +5` prints all lines starting with the fifth one, so the explanation for line two is off.